# Compatible and recommended data types for MS Access frontend / MySQL backend

Tags: mysql, ms-access, types

I need a list of recommended MySQL data types to use when using Microsoft Access as the front end. Can anyone point me to a succinct article on the net, or post a list here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this: [**Using Connector/ODBC with Microsoft Applications**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft.html)

> For all versions of Access, you should enable the Connector/ODBC Return matching rows  option. For Access 2.0, you should additionally enable the Simulate ODBC 1.0 option.
>
> You should have a TIMESTAMP column in all tables that you want to be able to update. For maximum portability, do not use a length specification in the column declaration (which is unsupported within MySQL in versions earlier than 4.1).
>
> ...
>
> Access cannot always handle the MySQL DATE column properly. If you have a problem with these, change the columns to DATETIME.
>
> ....

Comment: Thanks - Using Connector/ODBC with Microsoft Applications is a good source.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a comparison](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_datatypes.asp) of MS Access, MySQL, and SQL Server datatypes.

There are a lot of tricky issues to watch for; in some cases, Access and MySQL give the same name to different data types, e.g.

- **TEXT** in Access is 255 characters (similar to MySQL's **TINYTEXT**)
- **TEXT** in MySQL is 65535 characters (similar to Access's **MEMO**)

So if you use a **TEXT** field in MySQL, you'll have to access it as a **MEMO** in Access.

Number types can be tricky, too. MySQL has both signed and unsigned versions of each type, but Access doesn't. For example,

- **BYTE** in Access is equivalent to MySQL's **TINYINT UNSIGNED**
- **INTEGER** in Access is equivalent to MySQL's **SMALLINT** (signed)